# Excel - Writing Macros that will write on the next line

Tags: vba, excel

I apologize in advance if my question is too simplistic but I'm rather new to coding.

I'm trying to gather an information from a table and have the code list it out on separate lines.

The problem is that I'm trying to figure out a function that write on the cell or cells below the cell with the function.

For example, if I enter my function gatherinfo(x,y,z) into A1, I want the output to be written on A1, A2, and A3 (assuming that it has three different outputs).

I've been trying to look around for a function/code that represents the cell that the formula is put into but I'm having a tough time looking for it. I know that Activecell function works when I click on the cell and then run the macro. But I want a function that will just work off of the cell that contains that function (without depending on the active cell).

I hope that I'm making some sense. Thanks all in advance for your help!!

Comment: short answer - use the "cells" function in vba.  Set a range variable equal to the current cell and use a for loop to write text to the desired numbers of rows.  You can iterate through each row by using the variable for the active cell - call "currentrng" currentrnf.Cells(i,1) where i is variable that loops through the for statement

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code **inside** the worksheet code object :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Formula Like "=gatherinfo(*,*,*)" Then
            MsgBox "The formula " & Target.Formula & " was added to the cell " & Target.Address & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do something with it!"
        End If
    End If 
End Sub
```

**Worksheet code object :** 
[image]

You can then play around with the content of your worksheet and whenever you enter the function "gatherinfo" with 3 parameters, VBA will handle what to do. To know the row and column of the "Target" cell, you can use properties such as `.Row` and `.Column`.